# A combination of answers fixed my issue. What do I do?

Tags: discussion

Okay, for [JQuery Validate custom method not working after jquery.load()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31383898/jquery-validate-custom-method-not-working-after-jquery-load/31384187?noredirect=1#comment50745650_31384187) a combination of the only answer's **comment** and the "this question is related" fixed my particular issue.

Do I handle this by upvoting the only answer and marking it as accepted even though the answer itself was wrong? Do I upvote and post the combined correct answer? Do I comment him to include the code from the suggested duplicate and his comment in the answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Upvoting incorrect answers would tend to mislead other readers, your votes are your own of course but I wouldn't do that.

Add a new comment for the writer of the answer's comment suggesting that he expand the comment into an answer. If that works, great otherwise wait a bit and if nothing happens, write your own answer acknowledging the comment and commenter (possibly as a community wiki if you feel guilty about any rep you might acquire)